# Is there an option to Interrupt (stop) the component life cycle

Tags: angular

I’m working on RBAC implementation in my angular app. I want to interrupt (stop) the component lifecycle and the rendering of the component template (and child components / templates). If user doesn’t entitle.
I have created directive to manage the UI behavior but want to stop the .ts code execution too.
Do angular have any option or can I restrict or override child component lifecycle from parent component?

I am implementing entitlement and want to check user detail before component load to avoid execution of typescript code. I have tried with base service to check and restrict it.

Comment: "I am implementing entitlement and want to check user detail before component load" - I would do that with router and route guards.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides [route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) to perform this kinds of check before loading components.

Create Guard as below:

```
export class AccessGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor() { }
    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        // Check if user is entitled, then return true otherwise return false.
    }
}
```

You may also implements `CanActivateChild` in addition to `CanActivate` and provide appropriate implementation of **canActivateChild** method to enable checking before loading particular component's child routes.

Use this guard in routes configuration as below:

```
{
    path: 'protected', component: MyProtectedComponent, canActivate: [AccessGuard]
}
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Please create resolver like demo.resolver.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

 @Injectable()
 export class DemoResolver implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {
 constructor() {}
 resolve() {
     return Observable.of('Hello Alligator!').delay(2000);
    }
 }


//Routes
import { DemoResolver } from './demo.resolver';
{
  path: 'top',
  component: TopComponent,
  resolve: { message: DemoResolver }
}
```

so you can get data and check condition before component load
in resolver you can call API or whatever you want. that will  helpful for you.

Comment: I am agree with route guards but that will help to protect complete route. We want to restrict user at individual child components level means user might have access to route but doesn’t have entitle to view/edit specific child component of the route. We are maintaining authorization detail in separate service.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with route guards but that will help to protect complete route. We want to restrict user at individual child components level means user might have access to route but doesn’t have entitle to view/edit specific child component of the route. We are maintaining authorization detail in separate service.